# using errorlevel in a batch file to know if a program exited normally

Tags: batch-file

We have a program that is occasionally crashing. The customer runs the program from a scheduled task. When the program is run with a certain parameter, the program runs as an interface engine, creating a file and then ftp'ing the file to another server for import by another program.

I was wondering if I might have the scheduled task instead run a batch file. The batch file would run the program and check `errorlevel` as the program exits. If `errorlevel` is not equal to zero, then batch file would run the program again. Does anyone see problem with my plan to use `errorlevel` in a batch file?

Here's an example of the batch file:

```
:start    
myPgm.exe intfc    
if errorlevel <> 0 then start
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would write it like so:

```
:start
myPgm.exe intfc
IF %errorlevel% NEQ 0 GOTO :error
GOTO :end
:error
echo There was an error.
EXIT 1
:end
echo End.
EXIT 0
```

Comment: Your note is OK, but your code would give a syntax error.

Comment: No, you misunderstood. You need either `if %errorlevel% neq 0 ...` or `if errorlevel 1 ...`. The last form assumes the errorlevel is never negative. Your code is neither and raises a syntax error.

Answer (score 4):

Your IF statement is wrong. It should read

```
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto start
```

Or your script could read

```
:start
myPgm.exe intfc || goto start
```

Comment: Thanks for that feedback.  I plan to have my pgm set errorlevel on startup to a non-zero number, and then, on normal exit, set it back to zero.  Do you know if another program running on the server might also set errorlevel?

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/09/26/8965755.aspx  for the difference between ERRORLEVEL and %ERRORLEVEL%