# How to make a batch file that can evaluate the answer of a user prompt in a message box?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I don't know how to make a .bat file that can use `vbyes` or `vbno`.

I tried this:

```
@echo off
color 0a
cls
echo Hi %USERNAME%
pause >nul

echo a = msgbox("Hello",4+16,"Hi bruh")>hi.vbs
start hi.vbs
if a = vbYes then goto hello2
else
goto hello1
pause >nul

:hello
echo Hello1
pause >nul
exit

:hello2
echo Hello2
pause >nul
exit
```

But it didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Given a *properly written* .vbs file, you can get it to return a value: [How do I return an exit code from a VBScript console application](http://stackoverflow.com/q/187040/1115360). You can then check that value in the batch file with `errorlevel`: [using errorlevel in a batch file to know if a program exited normally](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17076252/1115360). If that is what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use VBScript constants or variables in batch files. You need to have the VBScript return the status code of the `MsgBox` as its exit code and then evaluate the `%errorlevel%` variable in your batch script:

```
>hi.vbs echo a = MsgBox("Hello",4+16,"Hi bruh")
>>hi.vbs echo WScript.Quit a

cscript //nologo hi.vbs
set "exitcode=%errorlevel%"

if %exitcode% equ 6 then goto hello2
if %exitcode% equ 7 then goto hello1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not *directly* use VBScript constants nor code in batch files; you need to explicitly define the values of the desired constants and create a .VBS file separated from the .BAT one. However, there is another programming language similar to VBScript in several aspects, called [JScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/hbxc2t98(vs.85).aspx), that *can* be used in the same Batch .BAT file via a simple trick; you just need to enclose the Batch code between these lines:

```
@set @x=0 /*


rem End of Batch section */
```

... and place the JScript code at end of the file. For example:

```
@set @x=0 /*

@echo off
color 0a
cls
echo Hi %USERNAME%
pause >nul

rem Define some useful constants
set /A vbYes=6, vbNo=7

rem Execute *this same* Batch file as a JScript one
cscript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"
if %errorlevel% == %vbYes% (
   echo Hello2 = Yes
) else (
   echo Hello1 = No
)
pause >nul
exit

rem End of Batch section */

// Start of JScript section

// Usage of Popup method: .Popup(strText,[nSecondsToWait],[strTitle],[nType])

var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WScript.Quit(WshShell.Popup("Hello",0,"Hi bruh",4+16));
```

Many facilities available in VBScript are very similar that those in JScript and just differ in details. For example, the VBScript `msgbox` is called [Popup method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x83z1d9f(v=vs.84).aspx) in JScript, so the conversion of short code sections from one language to the other one should have no problems...